# Как добавить данные в бинарный файл без удаления предыдущих данных

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть функция, добавляющая несколько элементов структуры в бинарный файл, через fwrite получается, что функция при запуске каждый раз перезаписывает данные, а не добавляет.Пыталась через fseek переместить указатель в конец, все равно не работает. Как можно реализовать именно добавление?

```
struct contact
    {
        char nomer[50];
        char adress[50];
        char sname[50];
    };

int add_kontakt()
{
    system("cls");
    unsigned int n;
    cout << "\nВведите количество добавляемых контактов:";
    cin >> n;
    contact *buf = new contact[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nВведите фамилию:";
        cin >> buf[i].sname;
        cout << "\nВведите номер телефона";
        cin >> buf[i].nomer;
        cout << "\nВведите адрес абонента:";
        cin >> buf[i].adress;
    }
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telobook.dot", "w+b");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(contact), n, f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем же использовать такую дичайшую смесь плюсов и сей? Есть ведь [`std::fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открывайте файл не с параметром "w+b", а с параметром "a" (append). Тогда не нужно никаких fseek. fwrite будет писать в конец файла.

Comment: Только вот `b` надо бы оставить.